# SSD Temperture Increases during idle

Tags: linux, ssd, mdraid

I have 4 Samsung 850 EVO SSDs in a mdraid 10 array inside a high performance simple NAS. running Centos6.8 minimal. I have found that the SSD tempertures start to increase on their own without any disk io. this happens to only some of the drives at a time. once the drive reasches 40c the activity led starts to flash. the drives are housed in good airflow. top and iotop show no processes accessing the raid at all. it happens at random, after boot, but one or two drives are always doing this. sometimes all of them. i have a fifth SSD as system drive with OS and that nevr has the problem. I cannot find what is causing this. Is this something to do with the EVO 850 Dynamic Temp Control, and why would it increase the temp. i'm at a loss, any help well apprieciated to get to the bottom of this. Occassionaly i have had 1 or 2 of the drives drop out of the array. the logs are not showing cause, only affect.

Comment: They're a consumer disk - why are you using them in a production datacentre environment?

Comment: Where's the mention of a production datacentre?

Comment: In the fact you're asking the question on Serverfault - as I'm sure you read when you signed up for this site we're about professional sysadmins working in a production environment - our sister site Superuser.com is for home or lab questions, again this is mentioned when you sign up.

Comment: even though it has nothing to do with the question i asked. i am a sysadmin working in a television post production enviroment. my systems are all about giving fast datastreams to editors for a short period of time during mobile post production. not 24/7. i have used consumer drives for this task for many years and have had no problem in there use. break em and chuck em away. i use enterprise drives in my fixed installations that are expected to be 24/7. so no i'm not a home user and its not a lab, its just different from what you do, but not wrong. so the question still sits.